# Application more than actual Question I am answering?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have this hypothetical thought experiment is to find two arbitrary functions with $\mathrm{i}$ starting point \begin{equation}\sum_{n=i}^\infty \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} \end{equation} Converges, and that the following converges as well: \begin{equation} \sum_{n=i}^\infty \frac{f'(n)}{g'(n)} \end{equation}
My question is how would I go about doing so in a coordinated, pragmatic way? They don't have to converge to the same number. I started by testing algebraic functions, and trigonometric, and transcendental. It's ok if this is not possible as well, I would like to just for the gain of the skill of developing a rationale for math intuition. This is not a homework exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. The best way to develop intuition is to look for simple examples. I think that counts as pragmatic. In this case think about what happens if $f$ and $g$ are each polynomials, or even just powers of $x$. Think about their degrees.

Comment: [Initial](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+n%5E3%2Fn%5E5%2C+n%3D1+to+infinity) and  [Derivative](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%283n%5E2%29%2F%285n%5E4%29%2C+n%3D1+to+infinity)

Comment: I found one set of f and g functions that are algebraic that converted by p-series.

Comment: You might even be able to guess (and prove) a theorem telling you when this happens (for polynomials). It's useful too to look for examples where it fails.

Comment: Is it the integral test, or the p-series test? Because these start at 1.

Comment: In any convergence test it does not matter where you start. Only what happens for large $n$ matters. PS. Can you find examples where both limits exist and are equal?